# Palindrome in Python not working

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

I am trying to make a simple program that displays the palindrome numbers between 2 numbers in Python3 but it doesn't seem to work. I get only 4 output which are 1,2,4 and 8. What about the other numbers like 11, 22, 33, ..., 111, 121,131,..., 191, 222, etc?

Here is my code. I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
a = 0
b = 500
a += 1
for i in range(a,b):
    if(str(a) == str(a)[::-1]):
        print(a)
        a += a
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
for i in range (0, 500):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        print(i)
```

Comment: That silly mistake. Thanks a lot. I wouldn't have seen this if I looked at it for an hour lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> palindromes = [a for a in range(500) if str(a) == str(a)[::-1]]
>>> palindromes
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111, 121, 131,
 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212, 222, 232, 242, 252, 262, 272, 282, 292, 303, 
 313, 323, 333, 343, 353, 363, 373, 383, 393, 404, 414, 424, 434, 444, 454, 464, 474,
 484, 494]
```

That shows you the principle. If you want to do it in a function, you can use `yield` instead of constructing the whole list in memory (much more efficient):

```
>>> def palindromes(a, b):                                                  
...   """Return palindromes in closed interval from a to b"""               
...   for i in range(a, b):                                                 
...     if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:                                          
...       yield i                                                           
...                                                                         
>>> list(palindromes(0, 500))                                               
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212, 222, 232, 242, 252, 262, 272, 282, 292, 303, 313, 323, 333, 343, 353, 363, 373, 383, 393, 404, 414, 424, 434, 444, 454, 464, 474, 484, 494]
```